# Max date function in summary table Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using the summarize function to group items by job, and find the latest ship date for any items on that job using the MAX function. For whatever reason on some of the lines (about 3%), the max function doesn't seem to work. Doing some digging it looks like the MIN function seems to give me the result I'm looking for, anyone have ideas on why this is? Below is the code I'm using, as well as a picture of one job that I'm having issues with. [image: Data]

```
Data summarized = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        Data, Data[SLT - SO#],
        "Max Ship Date", Max(Data[SO Seq Actual Del Date]),
        "Min Ship Date", MIN(Data[SO Seq Actual Del Date])
        )
```

Comment: Is `[SO Seq Actual Del Date]` a date or a string?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data summarized =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[SLT - SO#] ),
    "Max Ship Date", CALCULATE ( MAX ( Data[SO Seq Actual Del Date] ) ),
    "Min Ship Date", CALCULATE ( MIN ( Data[SO Seq Actual Del Date] ) )
)
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible to share your model view ? You have a date table?

Comment: Was able to figure it out- the data type for SO Seq Actual Del Date was text and not a date, thank you for your help though

Comment: You're welcome! I am pleased that your problem is solved.